# Can we add SPFx webpart as a personal/static tab in MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any news or timeframe as to when we could expect SPFx webparts to be available as Personal (Static) tabs in MS Teams?

As far as I can tell this is not yet possible, and only Team tabs are supported?

Comment: Please have a look at documentation on [Building Microsoft Teams tab using SharePoint Framework - Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-in-sharepoint).

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I mean the other way around. Building an SPFx webpart to be shown inside MS Teams. Now I know this can be done for a Team tab, but not (yet) for a Static/personal tab. My question is if or when this would be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SPFx 1.10 has been released, this is now supported.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab#updating-the-web-part-manifest-to-make-it-available-for-microsoft-teams:

> Starting from the SharePoint Framework 1.10 version, you can also
>   expose SharePoint Framework web parts as personal Microsoft Teams
>   apps. This can be controlled by including "TeamsPersonalApp" in the
>   supportedHosts value.